# How do I add instances to the Web/Types section?

Tags: ihp

Currently, I am making program to help book appointments. Part of that includes making timeslots. In my program I have created the following instance for a selectField option in a form

```
instance CanSelect User where
    type SelectValue User = Id User
    selectValue user = get #id user
    selectLabel user = get #displayName user
```

This is in Web/View/Timeslots/New.hs, but to limit the amount of duplication, I was advised to move this to Web/Types.hs. When I copy-paste this into Web/Types.hs, I get this error:

Web/Types.hs:17:10: error:
Not in scope: type constructor or class `CanSelect'
|
17 | instance CanSelect User where
|          ^^^^^^^^^

I have no idea how to fix this

Edit: I have fixed this by defining a class for CanSelect in the Web/Types.hs section, but have some type errors

```
class CanSelect model where
    type SelectValue model :: Id model
    selectLabel :: model -> Text
    selectValue :: model -> Id model

instance CanSelect User where
    type SelectValue User = Id User
    selectValue user = get #id user
    selectLabel user = get #displayName user
```

The error message reads:

- Couldn't match kind `*' with` Id' "users"'
  Expected kind `Id User', but` Id User' has kind `*'

  - In the type `Id User' In the type instance declaration for` SelectValue'
    In the instance declaration for `CanSelect User'

Answer (score 1):

This instance actually belongs to `Application/Helper/View.hs`. That file already imports the `CanSelect` class, so this should fix the issue.

Also regarding your code example: The latest IHP version now supports Haskell's new dot notation, so you can replace the `get #something` like this:

```hs
instance CanSelect User where
    type SelectValue User = Id User
    selectValue user = user.id
    selectLabel user = user.displayName
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! If I add this instance in the Application/Helper/View.hs section, I get an error as the User is not defined. Where would I go to define it? Also, is there a way to get this to work by moving it to Web/Types.hs or is this just the easiest way to make the instance available in multiple views? Lastly, thank you for informing me about the dot notation! The code looks much cleaner!

Comment: This error can be fixed by adding an `import Generated.Types` to the top of the file. You can also get this to work in `Web.Types`, but it's not the suggested way how it's typically done in IHP apps